# SQL Server creates different plans when OR condition is re-arranged

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, optimization, execution-plan

I was reviewing an under-performing query which looks like this:

```
WHERE manymany.Active = -1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.WebsiteID = @P1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ISNULL(manymany.FromDate, '1950-01-01') AND ISNULL(manymany.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN main.FromDate AND ISNULL(main.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND (main.TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR main.TextCol2 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY aux.SortCode
```

I accidentally used SSMS query designer on this query and it re-wrote the query as follows:

```
WHERE manymany.Active = -1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.WebsiteID = @P2
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ISNULL(manymany.FromDate, '1950-01-01') AND ISNULL(manymany.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN main.FromDate AND ISNULL(main.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.TextCol1 IS NOT NULL

   OR manymany.Active = -1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.WebsiteID = @P2
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ISNULL(manymany.FromDate, '1950-01-01') AND ISNULL(manymany.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN main.FromDate AND ISNULL(main.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.TextCol2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY aux.SortCode
```

If you look closely you'll notice that it simply expanded the `OR` condition by repeating all conditions i.e. it changed `a AND (b OR c)` to `(a AND b) OR (a AND c)`.

**The resulting query was 50% smaller in terms of cost and 33% smaller in terms of execution time.** I simply do not understand why re-arranging the `OR` condition changed the plan when both queries are identical (?). I could have expanded the `OR` condition myself by copy-pasting the conditions but why should I?

### [**Paste the plan**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkpY6MpLV) and screenshot:

[image: Execution Plans]

### Number of rows:

```
main     2718
manymany 188761
aux      19
```

### Notes:

- TextCol1 and TextCol2 are `text` datatype and cannot be indexed
- There are avg. 170.20 records in manymany table per website id

Comment: For to understand (or at least to try to do it) you must show table's DDL. A simple example - if there exists 2 separate indices which can be used to optimize (a AND b) and (a AND c) conditions separately, they can be used in "expanded" variant, but cannot in "base" one...

Comment: @Akina I have covering indexes for all where clauses except the table that is involved in `IS NOT NULL`... those columns are of `text` datatype.

Comment: Adding the query plan's to pastetheplan.com would be helpful

Comment: If you paste whole query with all joins that will help everyone understand better. Also this depends on which table is aliased `main`,(how many records each table contains,) similarly apply for `manymany` and `aux` aliased tables and how you join them.

Comment: I have added plan details.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements 9with all indexes) and the full query. The `FROM` clause at least is essential in understanding how the plan may be produced.

Comment: Also: are these actual plans or estimated ones? What are the actual execution times of the 2 queries?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ these are actual plans. The execution times are in fractions of seconds but the smaller one was faster when i checked the numbers inside dm_exec_query_stats.

Answer (score 2):

> But why doesn't SQL server sees both queries as one? After all, a AND
>   (b OR c) = (a AND b) OR (a AND c)?

Logically it is the same, and it will get the same results.

**Assumptions**

My assumptions are that for the 'faster' plan, the optimizer is not considering some filter statements at the top of the `OR` to be the same as some filter statements at the bottom.  I might be entirely off base here.

the reasoning for getting these assumptions are based on this filter predicate:

This filter predicate uses the result of the join between the `Main` table and `manymany` table. 
[image]

Notice that **EXPR1021** and **EXPR1022** in this filter are expressions  created from the scalar operator on the `manymany` table.

[image]

This filter  consists of two parts, the first one with `(.. AND .. OR .. AND ..)`
and the second one plain `AND` filtering

```
(getdate()>=[Expr1021] 
AND getdate()<=[Expr1022] 
AND getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL 
OR getdate()>=[Expr1021] 
AND getdate()<=[Expr1022]
 AND getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL) 

 AND (getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL OR getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL)
```

As you can see, the only difference above and below the `OR` in the first part of this filter is

```
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL
```

**VS**

```
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL
```

And the second part needs to be true no matter what, as they are `AND` predicates without any `OR`'s.

Resulting in extra calculations of the same functions, that in my opinion are not needed. 
Again, my guess here is that the reason that sql server does these calculations is that it does not know that they are the same.

For some other parts of the where clause, it does know that these are the same, e.g. In the main table, the statusid = 1 is only evaluated once:

[image]

And in the `manymany` table, the same statement is evaluated twice:

[image]

In the 'slow' plan, the statements are not added together with `OR` clauses, and that is why the optimizer is generating a different plan, applying filter predicates on the tables separately (and no duplicate filters).

[image]

[image]

**End of assumptions**

**Comparison of the two plans**

I think that you got lucky with the performance of the 'fast' plan, but that the 'fast' plan might turn ugly when the matching data increases. It can depend on where and when you are applying your filters *(and other factors)*.

**The fast plan filtering**

In the 'fast' plan: sql server applies some of the filters after the join of
  the `main` table with the `manymany` table as a result of different combinations with the two `OR`'s  + (`AND ... AND ... AND...`) blocks. 
The columns from the `maintable` are filtered after finding all the possible combinations with the `manymany` table.

As a result, the same predicate is executed twice on the `manymany` table:

[image]
For the predicates above and below the `OR`.

But this is not the case for some of the seek predicates on the `main` table

[image]

After this the join happens, and an even bigger filter predicate on the results of the join between `main` and `manymany` happens, again for all the possible combinations
[image]

Notice that **EXPR1021** and **EXPR1022** in this filter are expressions  created from the scalar operator on the `manymany` table.

[image]

This filter  consists of two parts, the first one with `(.. AND .. OR .. AND ..)`
and the second one plain `AND` filtering

```
(getdate()>=[Expr1021] 
AND getdate()<=[Expr1022] 
AND getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL 
OR getdate()>=[Expr1021] 
AND getdate()<=[Expr1022]
 AND getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL) 

 AND (getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL OR getdate()>=[DB1].[dbo].[main].[FromDate] 
 AND getdate()<=isnull([DB1].[dbo].[main].[UptoDate],'2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
 AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL)
```

As you can see, the only difference above and below the `OR` in the first part of this filter is

```
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol1] IS NOT NULL
```

**VS**

```
AND [DB1].[dbo].[main].[TextCol2] IS NOT NULL
```

And the second part needs to be true no matter what, as they are `AND` predicates without any `OR`'s.

Resulting in extra calculations that in my opinion are not needed.

**The slow plan filtering**

In the 'slow' plan: sql server applies the filter directly to the
Main table as a result of the `AND (TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR TextCol2 IS NOT NULL`) part and then joins with the `manymany` table to filter out the rest to get to 15 rows.

**`Main` table filters**

[image]

[image]

**`manymany` table filters**

[image]

---

Some other, sometimes overlapping information:

**The slower plan**

When we look at the slower plan, the clustered index PK_main is used, into a compute scalar, filter  and nested loops operator:

[image]

When we compare this with the **estimated rows** to be returned, we see a difference:
[image]

It is estimating 93 rows to be returned by the predicate on the scan:

[image]

Which is actually about 20x less than what was expected, which is **1947 rows**.

Afterwards, the Compute scalar or this statement:

```
 , CASE WHEN TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR TextCol2 IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS MoreFlag
 , CASE WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN Stars END AS Rating
```

is evaluated on these 1947 rows.

Then the filter operator (`main.TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR main.TextCol2 IS NOT NULL`) to reduce it to 1374 rows.

After this, join these 1374 rows to the `dbo.manymany` table to get 15 rows returned.

**The faster plan**

The faster plan is using the NC index: `CVR_main_4` on `the dbo.Main` table,
[image]

It is filtering with a seek predicate, returning 27 rows to the `nested loops` Join operator, again joining with the `dbo.manymany` table.

And the actual rows returned are even lower than the **estimated rows**:

[image]

*27 actual rows for an estimate of 152 rows*

**Filtering**

A big difference is where the filtering happens, where on the 'slower' plan this is being done directly on the `dbo.Main` table:

With the predicate: `TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR TextCol2 IS NOT NULL`

[image]

*And is applying this filter to 1943 rows.*

With the other filtering happening directly on the `dbo.manymany` table

[image]
*(seek) predicates on `dbo.manymany`*

While the other `OR`, on the 'faster' plan, is being filtered after the join from `dbo.Main` to `dbo.manymany`, and results in a much bigger filter, on the 27 rows.

[image]

*Much bigger filter with multiple `OR`'s on 27 rows.*

Another difference is the Key lookup operator:

[image]

which gets 10 additional columns from the clustered index, but only has to do this for 27 rows.

[image]

[image]

Another reason that the optimizer chooses the 'slower' plan might be because the optimizer  thinks not looking up the other columns would be better.

---

**Is the fast plan even faster, or always going to be 'faster'?**

I do think that, if the data passing through the filter increases, the 'slow' plan will be better. Not only due to the key lookup, but also due to the bigger filter operator further down in the plan.

If that happens, next  to indexing. You could improve the filtering by splitting the query into multiple parts using a `UNION` statement.

Like so:

```
SELECT main.MainID, Title, Column1, Column2, Column7, Column4, Column6, Column3, Column5
     , CASE WHEN TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR TextCol2 IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS MoreFlag
     , CASE WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN Stars END AS Rating
FROM manymany
INNER JOIN main ON manymany.MainID = main.MainID
LEFT JOIN aux ON manymany.AuxID = aux.AuxID
WHERE manymany.WebsiteID = @P1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.Active = -1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ISNULL(manymany.FromDate, '1950-01-01') AND ISNULL(manymany.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN main.FromDate AND ISNULL(main.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND TextCol1 IS NOT NULL

 UNION 

 SELECT main.MainID, Title, Column1, Column2, Column7, Column4, Column6, Column3, Column5
     , CASE WHEN TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR TextCol2 IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS MoreFlag
     , CASE WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN Stars END AS Rating
FROM manymany
INNER JOIN main ON manymany.MainID = main.MainID
LEFT JOIN aux ON manymany.AuxID = aux.AuxID
WHERE manymany.WebsiteID = @P1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.Active = -1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ISNULL(manymany.FromDate, '1950-01-01') AND ISNULL(manymany.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN main.FromDate AND ISNULL(main.UptoDate, '2050-01-01')
  AND TextCol2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SortCode;
```

Comment: But why doesn't SQL server sees both queries as one? After all, `a AND (b OR c)` = `(a AND b) OR (a AND c)`?

Comment: @SalmanA Lets say a belongs to the manymany table and B and C belongs to the Main table .For `a AND (b OR c)` it is resembling of the slow query, where `b` or `c` is directly filtered on the main table, as to then join with `a` (ManyMany) to get the remaining results. `(a and b) or (a and c)` is filtering after the join of the two tables, to filter these out after getting the resultset of the join Because `a` and `c` can only be filtered together with `a` and `b`.

Comment: @SalmanA SQL does not see its same because `1*1` and `1+1` is not same for SQL. This is computer and machine language at the end. If it becomes smart enough why  DBA's are required.!?

Comment: @RandiVertongen here you explain why the different plans have different performance and which one should be better, but I the OP's question is why writing 2 expressions *that are completely equivalent* affect the optimizer's plans. SQL is (in theory) a declarative language (not imperative), so we tell the engine **what** we want and not **how** it should do. For this example it seems that we can influence the how.

Comment: @EzLo You are correct, I have added my assumptions, I might be entirely off base though.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, It has to start with a scan whereas with the second it was able to utilize the non-clustered index for a seek.

Think about it like you have 100 marbles in a bag and you want to audit them to pick out only the ones that are blue and white or blue and red.

The first query is saying, look through each of the 100 marbles and pick out all the blue.  Once you've done that, check all them and see if there are any with white or red.

The second query is saying go into the bag and only grab blue and white or blue and red marbles.

The second query would be faster because you wouldn't have to look at each marble for just the blue first. You could combine that step with what you really wanted which was blue and white or blue and red.

That's how I look at it anyways.  Ultimately the first query required a table scan and the second used the seek right from the beginning.  It still had to do a key lookup and a scan because the non-clustered index didn't have all the information it needed, but by that point it had a much smaller set of data to look through so it was faster.

Answer (score 0):

Plan Link is not working.

You have provided incomplete info.It is important to know table join column 
and their data type.

WHAT is `aux.SortCode` ? WHAT is `aux` alias ? Where it is in Query ?

There is further scope to rearrange the query.

In this case,

```
AND (main.TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR main.TextCol2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Sql Optimizer `Cardianility Estimate` is very poor.

Repeating same condition with `OR` is bad idea.

You can put `many` table record in `#Temp` table or `CTE`

Then finally join `manymany` with `#Temp` table.

```
DECLARE @Dt Datetime=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select many.Col,many.OnlyRequiredColumn
from many into #Temp
WHERE main.Active = -1
  AND main.StatusID = 1
  AND (main.FromDate>=@Dt AND main.UptoDate<=@Dt)
  AND (main.TextCol1 IS NOT NULL OR main.TextCol2 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY aux.SortCode
```

If `#Temp` have more than 100/200 record then you can create `index` on the Column which Join with manymany.

```
select *
from manymany
join #Temp on manymany.somecolumn=#temp.somecolumn
WHERE manymany.Active = -1
  AND manymany.Check1 = -1
  AND manymany.WebsiteID = @P1
  AND (manymany.FromDate>=@Dt AND manymany.UptoDate<=@Dt)
--ORDER BY aux.SortCode
```